# Update column with same data hashed

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column in the user table where there are plain text passwords stored. They need to be hashed and I don't want the users to notice this change.

```
$users = SELECT * FROM user

foreach ($users as $user):
UPDATE user SET password = 'new value'
endforeach;
```

However, how do I pass in all the plain text passwords and hash them before updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL `UPDATE` statement can read the old values of table columns and use them in the assignment.

```
UPDATE user
SET password = HASH_FUNCTION(password);
```

Replace `HASH_FUNCTION` with the specific function you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to do a sha1 hash with a double salt: sha1($password . SALT) . SALT). I can't seem to figure out a way to implement this php function in the query.

Comment: Your question never said anything about PHP. It's only tagged `mysql`, so I thought you wanted a SQL solution.

Comment: It is possible with a SQL query as well, am I right? SHA1() is also a MySQL function. But for some reason I can't get this right.

Comment: If this is for actual security purposes, a sha1 hash is barely a bandaid.

Comment: I didn't specify which hash function to use.